# Text to Handwriting Conversion iPhone/ iPad

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

Hi I am very new to **iPad/iPhone** development I know that there are heaps of **iPhone/iPad** apps regarding **handwriting conversion to Text** and handwriting recognition as well but I need to develop an iPad app in which if I type in text it should be converted in to my own handwriting meaning text to handwriting conversion iPad app

First need to know is it possible and if possible are there any apps in the apple store for which I can get refer to I brainstormed a lot but text to handwriting seems quite a difficult task I presume so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible only if you create your custom font with your custom handwriting - each letter for each handwritten letter. It will never ever be like real handwriting and it would be just "close". Nevertheless, you don't need an iPad app to do that, because the main and hardest point here is creating your own font. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks I really appreciate your time for posting this answer

Comment: @Hardy you're always welcome)